# Iteration over String

Tags: python, iterator

I'm still learning so be gentle.

given the following code.

```
str = "sometext"
it = iter(str)
print it
print len(list(it))
print len(list(it))
```

I get the following output.

```
<iterator object at 0x1070b9990>
8
0
```

Why would the contents of the object only be usable once?

Comment: Why would the contents of the object only be usable once? -- this is what returned by iter()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterator is simply for single use (or better "consume content once") and be done:

```
>>> text = "sometext"
>>> it = iter(text)
>>> it
<iterator at 0x7f7ea01aead0>
>>> lst = list(it)
>>> lst
['s', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'e', 'x', 't']
```

The `list` has iterated over all the content and finished.

Trying to use the iterator once more:

```
>>> it.next()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-54f0920595b2> in <module>()
----> 1 it.next()
```

results in `StopIteration` exception.

To follow on, you have to create the iterator again:

```
>>> it = iter(text)
```

And use it. In fact iterating means calling `next()` on it (this is what `list` did internally):

```
>>> it.next()
's'
>>> it.next()
'o'
>>> it.next()
'm'
>>> it.next()
'e'
>>> it.next()
't'
>>> it.next()
'e'
>>> it.next()
'x'
>>> it.next()
't'
>>> it.next()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-54f0920595b2> in <module>()
----> 1 it.next()
```

Note, that `list` iteration (and `for` loops) do catch `StopIteration` exception and do not propagate it out as it is simple sign of "no more items to get".

Do you want next try? Get fresh iterator. This one got exhausted.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation.  I was thinking that if I was creating an object, I would be available to perform multiple operations on it.  Your explanation makes complete sense.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 5):

That's how iterators work: once you've iterated over certain elements, there's no going back other than by creating a new iterator and starting all over again.

Comment: ... or iterate over the string to begin with.